# Edit specific record from a line in text file and PHP

Tags: php, file, text

I'm trying to make a simple news hit counter with PHP and text file. i wrote a simple code to check and read the file:

**Text File:**

```
//Data in Source File
//Info: News-ID|Hits|Date
1|32|2013-9-25
2|241|2013-9-26
3|57|2013-9-27
```

**PHP File:**

```
//Get Source
$Source = ENGINE_DIR . '/data/top.txt';
$Read = file($Source);

//Add New Record
foreach($Read as $News){
  //Match News ID
  if($News[0] == "2"){
    //Add New Record and Update the Text File
  }
}
```

Problem is i can't change the news hits! For example, i need change hits from second line from **241** to **242** and write it again in to the txt file.

I searched in this site and Google and tried some ways but i couldn't fix that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the least, you're forgetting to write the increment back to the file. Also, you're going to want to parse each row into columns you can work with (delimited by a pipe `|`).

Untested code, but the idea is:

```
$Source = ENGINE_DIR . '/data/top.txt'; // you already have this line
$Read = file($Source); // and this one

foreach ( $Read as $LineNum => $News ) { // iterate through each line
    $NewsParts = explode('|',$News); // expand the line into pieces to work with
    if ( $NewsParts[0] == 2 ) { // if the first column is 2
        $NewsParts[1]++; // increment the second column
        $Read[$LineNum] = implode('|',$NewsParts); // glue the line back together, we're updating the Read array directly, rather than the copied variable $News
        break; // we're done so exit the loop, saving cycles
    }
}

$UpdatedContents = implode(PHP_EOL,$Read); // put the read lines back together (remember $Read as been updated) using "\n" or "\r\n" whichever is best for the OS you're running on
file_put_contents($Source,$UpdatedContents); // overwrite the file
```

Answer (score 2):

You could read the file and do something like this:

```
//Get Source
$Source = ENGINE_DIR . '/data/top.txt';
$Read = file($Source);

$News = array();

foreach ($Read as $line) {
    list($id, $views, $date) = explode('|', $line);
    $News[$id] = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'views' => $views,
        'date' => $date,
    );
}
```

At this point you have the array `$News` which contains every news item and you can change them as you wish (example: `$News[2]['views'] = 242;`).

The only thing you're missing now is the writing back to the file part, which is also easy.

```
$fh = fopen(ENGINE_DIR . '/data/top.txt', 'w'); //'w' mode opens the file for write and truncates it

foreach ($News as $item) {
    fwrite($fh, $item['id'] . '|' . $item['views'] . '|' . $item['date'] . "\n");
}

fclose($fh);
```

And that's it! :)

Comment: but it does not edit second line and after that i got too much empty line!

Comment: I gave you a solution to WORK with the data, not just increment a field, but you didn't see the forest through trees.

Comment: You're welcome. To edit the second line just put `$News[2]['views']++;` between the 2 pieces of code (the first one is making an array with all the data in the files and the second one writes that array to the disk).